# Sort by Date field which is a VARCHAR in the database

Tags: php, mysql

All,
I have the following query:

> SELECT ...
>   FROM....
>   WHERE...
>   ORDER BY gear_checkout_summary.check_out_date DESC";

I then have the following dates for example:
12/29/2012
11/30/2012
09/04/2012
07/21/2013
07/08/2013
06/29/2013

They are sorted this way when my results are returned. My data element is stored as VARCHAR(10) in my database since I messed up that design. Is there a way to change my query so it sorts the dates correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What an awful column. Not only use it *not* a DATE/DATETIME but it's *not* in a well-ordered date format (e.g. an ISO-8601 form like YYYY-MM-DD). So *fix* the data so that one of the above (preferably the first) is true. If the column can't be changed in the schema, fix/normalize the data for sake of the query so that order by works as it would normally.

Comment: its better to change the data type to date(), you can first copy the table and change data type of the original, then copy the data from another one.

Comment: Start over with the table. use a **NATIVE** date or datetime field type, and then your problem GOES AWAY. using text/varchar-type fields to store data that can be better represented as a native data type is almost always a horribly bad idea.

Comment: I wish I lived in the fantasy world with these other commenters where you can just change things in production the way you want or the way they should have been done. Because you know, there isn't anything that could go wrong with that in prod.

Comment: @Oberon My comment applies equally as well to dealing with bad data without changing the schema - *fix* it into something orderable. In any case, using correct methodologies - repeatable schema applications, tested DALs, reduced contact area, etc - makes this a "no brainer" for reasonable sized projects.

Comment: see my answer below mate. it converts your varchar to proper date format, which will then make is optimal for date comparisons

Comment: To add to what @user2246674 has said, you will INEVITABLY need to convert this field to a date format field.  You will already note that the solutions offered below do not allow for use of an index, so they will not be optimized.  If you want to be able to sort AND use an index, you need this to be a date field (or at the very minimum a YYYY-MM-DD formatted text field, which If you are going through to trouble to change should just be made a date field).

Comment: @Oberon Is it acceptable to use non-indexed queries in production?  The OP should absolutely look at changing this schema sooner rather than later.  If this is a brand new requirement which has been made and will require an index on this table, then absolutely the refactoring for this schema change should be made as part of this work.  If the table is so small that one might say "I don't really need an index." Then I would argue that this is a trivial application with minimal usage, such that making such a change now (before there might be heavy usage) would absolutely be required.

Comment: @MikeBrant `Is it acceptable to use non-indexed queries in production?` of course not. But that doesn't change the fact that there could be 100 different people relying on the data being setup exactly the way he has it, as it is in the systems that I work in. I hate the way the data is setup, but it has been estimated at around 400 total hours to fix it. I just see these sort of comments here alot and it makes me shake my head every time, I chimed up on this one because it's similar to the data I just referred to. In a perfect world...

Comment: @user1048676 see my answer below, it will fix your database to the proper datatype and changing the source code will probably be worth the extra time to make it right if at all possible.

Comment: Instead of changing the original column it may be easier and better to simply add a new date/datetime column and use triggers to update that column whenever to original column is set or changed. That way it should be possible to slowly refactor the existing code in small steps.

Comment: @h00ligan this is exactly what I have done before... Good suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(check_out_date, 7) DESC, check_out_date DESC
```

This first orders by the year using the `SUBSTR()` function. For rows that have the same year, it then orders by the date itself. This second-level ordering doesn't require `SUBSTR()` because `MM/DD` is already ordered properly.

Comment: @user2246674 It first orders by the year. For dates that are in the same year, it orders by the date within the year, which is already in a format that orders properly.

Comment: I think it may not be certain the position of the year if the date is stored in a `varchar` field (for example: `12/5/2013'), so this solution could generate some undesired output

Comment: @Barranka  His examples all have leading zeroes. I'm willing to assume that he's formatting them properly when inserting them.

Answer (score 2):

STR_TO_DATE will see your job

```
STR_TO_DATE(gear_checkout_summary.check_out_date, '%c/%e/%Y') // will give '2013-06-23' in Date format
```

This will convert your varchar field into date format.

Comment: On my system `DATE()` only recognizes `YYYY-MM-DD` date formats, not `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. The argument to the `DATE()` function is the column in the database, not a format string.

Comment: @Barmar dude, I'm giving a format to indicate what should go where. I'm not saying he should include the format, but rather the date (string) in that format

Comment: the whole problem is that his data is NOT in that format. The format of the data is a given, he can't change it.

Comment: how about now @Barmar?

Answer (score 2):

This would put the date in the proper MySQL date format and then ordering would be simple.

```
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE(gear_checkout_summary.check_out_date,"%m/%d/%Y") AS fixed_date
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY fixed_date DESC
```

As others have stated, you should fix the format in the database if at all anyway possible. You may need to change the insert statements, but it will be worth the extra work. Here is what you would need to do to format the dates in the database

```
ALTER TABLE gear_checkout_summary ADD check_out_date_temp DATE AFTER check_out_date;
UPDATE gear_checkout_summary SET check_out_date_temp = STR_TO_DATE(gear_checkout_summary.check_out_date,"%m/%d/%Y");
ALTER TABLE gear_checkout_summary DROP check_out_date;
ALTER TABLE gear_checkout_summary CHANGE check_out_date_temp check_out_date DATE;
```

Here is explanation of above code:

1. Create new column in your table.
2. Populate the new column with the dates from the previous column formatted correctly.
3. Drop the old bad formatted column.
4. rename new column to previous columns name.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't sort by a field not defined in the row source (the tables and/or queries in the `FROM` clause). I think the right way to do it is: `ORDER BY str_to_date(date_field, '%m/%d/%Y')`. Also, the date format in the OP is `mm-dd-yyyy` (not `dd/mm/yyyy`)

Comment: @Barranka This is perfectly valid, however it would also change the output format to a valid MySQL date format of YYYY-MM-DD, which may not be desired (though it should be). Coincidentally, this function would also come in useful when the OP makes his inevitable switch to real date format for that field.

Comment: @Barranka according to the OP his date format is `12/29/2012` err... nevermind mm/dd/yyyy fixed.

Comment: @MikeBrant if the user still wanted his original format he could select it besides this alias `fixed_date` and thanks for the confirmation of validity

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_to_date`:

```
select *
from your_table
order by STR_TO_DATE(yourDateField,'%m/%d/%Y') desc;
```

This will convert the string to a valid MySQL date. Check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

You **should** change your data type to `DATE`... it is the easiest and cleanest way to store dates.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all codes and at the end I achieve my sorting on varchar date with this code...

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(check_out_date, 7) DESC, ORDER BY SUBSTR(check_out_date, 1,2) DESC,ORDER BY SUBSTR(check_out_date, 4,2) DESC
```

First sort by year, then  by month and at the end by day...